# Скрыть блоки за рамки блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть блок, в блоке должны отображаются только 3 блока.
1-4 блоки `display: block`, остальные `:none`. Как выкинуть 4-ый блок за рамки. Все они должны стоять в ряд.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8hgxLj2c/)

### Спасибо.

```js
var elem1,
  collectionBlocks = document.getElementById('collection_divs');

elem1 = collectionBlocks.children[0];
setTimeout(function() {
  elem1.style.cssText = 'margin-left: -330px;\
               transition: 3s';
}, 3000);
```

```css
.div:nth-child(n + 5) {
  display: none;
}

#collection_divs {
  width: 950px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #804e49;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 2px;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #db5461;
}

.div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 490px;
  background-color: #ad6f6f;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #db5461;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.top_blocks {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #e7ac9c;
}

.top_blocks_img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 210px;
  background-color: #e3a7b1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #db5461;
}

.top_blocks_img img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 210px;
}

.top_blocks_discription {
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  height: 270px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.top_blocks_discription h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-top: -3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #e74f5e;
}

.top_blocks_discription p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Arial;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: auto 5px;
  word-spacing: 4px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 4px;
  color: #512020;
}

.top_blocks_discription p span a {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: white;
}

.top_blocks_discription button {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 25%;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 2px solid #db5461;
  background-color: #e3a7b1;
  transition: 0.6s;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.top_blocks_discription button:hover {
  width: 55%;
  margin: 0 22.5%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #b8858e;
}
```

```html
<div id="collection_divs">
  <div class="div">
    <div class="top_blocks">
      <div class="top_blocks_img">
        <img src="http://pitomcy.net/sites/pitomec/files/styles/300width/public/field/image/2013/12/07/trawa-maly-bokser-obroza.jpeg?itok=cGd4pdZE">
      </div>
      <div class="top_blocks_discription">
        <h3>Собаки крутые</h3>
        <p>
          &nbsp; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci omnis ab provident expedita fugit delectus eum ea quam, enim at! <br><span><a href="">... узнать больше</a></span>
        </p>
        <button>Заказать</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <div class="top_blocks">
      <div class="top_blocks_img">
        <img src="http://zoohelp.org/forum/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=49938.0;attach=65933;image">
      </div>
      <div class="top_blocks_discription">
        <h3>Собаки круче котов</h3>
        <p>
          &nbsp; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi mollitia minus, alias explicabo cupiditate magnam accusantium ducimus voluptatibus accusamus ipsam. <br><span><a href="">... узнать больше</a></span>
        </p>
        <button>Заказать</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <div class="top_blocks">
      <div class="top_blocks_img">
        <img src="https://zelenyjmir.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Sobaka-bokser-55-300x200.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="top_blocks_discription">
        <h3>Собака - друг человека</h3>
        <p>
          &nbsp; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima alias voluptatem, voluptates aspernatur tenetur enim facere incidunt. Sed, quas, ex?<br><span><a href="">...<span id="face"></span> узнать больше</a>
          </span>
        </p>
        <button>Заказать</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <div class="top_blocks">
      <div class="top_blocks_img">
        <img src="http://wallpaperscraft.ru/image/sobaka_morda_ovcharka_glaza_51259_300x210.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="top_blocks_discription">
        <h3>Собаки это супер</h3>
        <p>
          &nbsp; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet quaerat aut eveniet fugiat laboriosam, deleniti odio reiciendis enim nisi tempore. <br><span><a href="">... узнать больше</a></span>
        </p>
        <button>Заказать</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <div class="top_blocks">
      <div class="top_blocks_img">
        <img src="https://zelenyjmir.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Sobaka-bokser-55-300x200.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="top_blocks_discription">
        <h3>Собака - друг человека</h3>
        <p>
          &nbsp; Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima alias voluptatem, voluptates aspernatur tenetur enim facere incidunt. Sed, quas, ex?<br><span><a href="">...<span id="face"></span> узнать больше</a>
          </span>
        </p>
        <button>Заказать</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#collection_divs {
  width: 950px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #804e49;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 2px;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #db5461;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 490px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #ad6f6f;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #db5461;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Можно обернуть в дополнительный блок, для него прописать white-space: nowrap; Выстроить div в ряд disply : inline-block и убрать float: left, а также спрятать все что за рамками для collection_divs добавив oveflow: hidden

Comment: Все, спасибо. I understood you!